# Java word counting

Tags: java

I'm trying to count words by using whitespace as my indicator for when there is a new word.

My current code is returning crazy results for wordCounter, but my vowelCounter is working perfectly.

I apologize if this is a basic or simple question...I'm just starting out with Java and I would really appreciate any assistance!

```
    System.out.println("Please enter some text: ");
    String fileContent = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    int vowelCounter = 0;
    int wordCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length(); i++) {

        if(fileContent.charAt(i) == 'a' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'e' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'i'|| fileContent.charAt(i) == 'o' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'u')
            vowelCounter++;

    for (int j = 0; j < fileContent.length(); j++) {

        if (Character.isWhitespace(fileContent.charAt(j))) {
            wordCounter++;
        }
    }

    }
    System.out.println("\nVowel Counter: " + vowelCounter);
    System.out.println("Word Counter: " + wordCounter);
```

Comment: Here's a hint: try putting the loop for checking whitespace above the one for vowels, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

That is what happens when you have bad indentation. You are having nested for-loops instead of 2 separate for-loops.

Separate your loops like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length(); i++) {
    if(fileContent.charAt(i) == 'a' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'e' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'i'|| fileContent.charAt(i) == 'o' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'u')
        vowelCounter++;
}

for (int j = 0; j < fileContent.length(); j++) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(fileContent.charAt(j)))
        wordCounter++;
}
```

Or have them in 1 single for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length(); i++) {
    if(fileContent.charAt(i) == 'a' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'e' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'i'|| fileContent.charAt(i) == 'o' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'u')
        vowelCounter++;
    else if (Character.isWhitespace(fileContent.charAt(i))) {
        wordCounter++;
    }
}
```

---

Above all, to check that specific characters (such as vowels) exist in your string, you can do it as:

```
char ch = fileContent.charAt(i);
if("aeiou".contains("" + ch))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant loop inside your loop. Just add the second `if` to the same loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.length(); i++) {

    if(fileContent.charAt(i) == 'a' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'e' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'i'|| fileContent.charAt(i) == 'o' || fileContent.charAt(i) == 'u')
        vowelCounter++;

    else if (Character.isWhitespace(fileContent.charAt(i)))
        wordCounter++;

}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna add 1 to the wordcount because it ia counting the number of whitespaces. For eg: in "apple banana", there is 1 whitespace but 2 words. Besides that, counting whitespaces has shortcomings, for instance, when there are two or more consecutive whitespaces between the words.